# Seeking polygon data for upper tier local authorities in England

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I'm trying to draw an interactive map showing boundaries for upper tier local authorities in England, but can't find the polygon data I need.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need the [OS Boundary Line dataset](https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open/BoundaryLine) which is freely available under the [Open Government Licence](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/):

> From Euro constituencies to council wards, Boundary-Line™ maps every administrative boundary in detail for you.